# What tag attribute should I use for different meaning of some text

Tags: html, tags, seo

I want to give different name to the text I have like "wizerunek firmy" (it's corporate identity in Polish) and I want to put english translation of that text (because of SEO reasons). What tag and attribute should I use to have good semantic html? `alt` attribute is good candidate, but what tag? or maybe there is special tag just for this kind of things in html5.

Comment: I recommend "wizerunek firmy" as an :after element and hide the original text (the seo text)

Comment: @AdrianFlorescu I want them both to be in html. Because I found in adwords KeywordPlanner that people search for "corporate identity" even if language is Polish and no one search for "wizerunek firmy", but if google decide to show (instead of description) the text from body I want to have "wizerunek firmy". So what I want is to hide "corporate identity" from users and google, but have it affect the SEO and also I want to have semantic html.

Comment: Hiding text from users but making visible to indexers is black hat SEO, and may contribute to your page or site being penalised by Google. Just put the English translation in parentheses after the Polish.

Comment: @Alohci I don't want to hide it like display: none will do. I only want to have one visible and one alternative meaning that engine will see, but I don't want to be visible if google pick the text instead of description (so I need attribute for it and I want it to be semantic).

Comment: "Different name", "different meaning", "translation" -- what exactly?

Comment: @unor translation, but it should matter the semantic html should be the same.

Answer (score 1):

The appropriate element in most cases would be `span` (i.e., there is no element especially for offering translations). With `span`, you may only use the [global attributes](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/dom.html#global-attributes).

Of those global attributes, only the [`title` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/dom.html#attr-title) may show content to the user. The passage "could be a footnote or commentary on the text" might apply in your case (it’s not a 100% match, though). But don’t use it if the translation is important or relevant for the content!

As you want to offer a translation, you should use the [`lang` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/dom.html#attr-lang). Because the attribute applies to both, the element content as well as the attribute value, you need to add two `span` elements:

```
<span title="corporate identity" lang="en"><span lang="pl">wizerunek firmy</span></span>
```

(Depending on context, there might be more appropriate elements ([`abbr`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/text-level-semantics.html#the-abbr-element), [`b`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/text-level-semantics.html#the-b-element), [`dfn`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/text-level-semantics.html#the-dfn-element), [`i`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/text-level-semantics.html#the-i-element) etc.), but don’t use these in the general case, only if their definition applies to your specific use.)

If the translation is relevant/important, don’t hide it in a `title` attribute (many users/consumers won’t notice or can’t access it):

```html
wizerunek firmy (angielski: <span lang="en">corporate identity</span>)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like that:

```
<p>Is true that <i class="foreignphrase" lang="pl">Polska jest wspaniałe</i> all agree to that.</p>.
```

Comment: I want to have in html both phrases. and they should be next to each other connected semantically.

Answer (score 0):

the 'semantically correct' tag would all depend on where on the page your phrase is and what context it is used in.

Answer (score -1):

I think that the tag I'm looking for is em, and the code can look like:

```
<em alt="Corporate Identity">Wizerunek Firmy</em>
```

**EDIT**

if em and alt is not good then it can be:

```
<i title="Corporate Identity">Wizerunek Firmy</i>
```

Comment: No, you're definitely not looking for `<em>`. And alt is not a valid attribute of the em element anyway.

Comment: `<i>` would be better than `<em>` here, and `title` better than `alt`.

Comment: @Alohci I read this http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-i-element and you'r probably right, you can add another answer.